# why copy constructor use private property directly in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor

Look at following:

```
class node
{
    int freq;

public:
    node(const node &other)
    {
        freq = other.freq;
    }

    int getFreq()
    {
        return freq;
    }
};
```

It works well. However, when I replace `freq = obj.freq` with `freq = obj.getFreq()`, it gives me this error:

```
'int node::getFreq(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const node' to 'node &'
```

Why? `freq` is a private member, it makes more sense that we should use the interface `getFreq` to access it.

Comment: No, it makes more sense to access the data member directly, in the costructor initializaiton list. Otherwise you'r have to provide getters for every single data member in order to copy an object.

Comment: Also, your title does not match the question you seem to be asking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
`'int node::getFreq(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const node' to 'node &'`

Comment: **In the question....**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't compile, because your function is not declared `const`:

```
int getFreq() const; // accessor function that does not modify the object
```

Thus, you can not call it with `const` instance: `const node &obj`.

Accessing `obj.freq` works, because it adapts to the `const` instance, making `obj.freq` not modifiable - to do this with a member function would be a nonsense (code inside member function lacking `const` specifier might (and should) require modifiable entities).

Comment: could you pleas look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847779/how-to-convert-abstract-class-to-normal-class-without-overload-pure-virtual-func?noredirect=1#comment55460188_33847779

Comment: Accessing `obj.freq` works, actually because `node` class is a friend class to itself. You could change you answer.

Comment: No, it isn't? "freq is a private member" - you in the question.

Comment: yeah, freq is a private member. But node class's friend class could access node class's private member, and node class is friend class to itself.

Comment: You know about `friend` keyword, that's nice, but it doesn't make sense to mention it here. This is all about member function without `const` specifier vs non-const member data, nothing else.