# how to convert abstract class to normal class without overload pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, virtual

look at following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual int getN() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    int n = 2;
public:
    int getN() { return n; }
};
class C : public A
{
    // do not contain property n, it nolonger need getN();
};
```

class A is a abstract class. Now I have class C derived from A. But it dose not like class B has a property **n**. So I can't overload `getN()`, and then class C is a abstract class, which I cannot instantiate it. 
So if I want instantiate class C, what should I do?

Comment: Make `getN()` private in `C`.

Comment: Since class A is unsuitable as a base of C, class A is unsuitable as a base of C. Dang. I'm smart. S, M, R, T.

Comment: your design is wrong. Base class should have properties that are interest to all sub-classes. In your example, you re better off moving getN() to B, as it's not needed by C

Comment: @Nandu class A has common properties, you could add some to it

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah, good idea!!! it works, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance represents a "kind-of" relationship.

Since `C` does not have a `getN()` method, it cannot be a "kind of" `A` since anyone holding a reference to an `A` has the right to expect `getN()` to be present.

They have this right because you asserted it by putting `getN` in the public virtual interface of `A`.

Moral of the story - avoid inheritance if you can. Prefer encapsulation.

Comment: This is pretty much the key point- if you can't offer the contract, *don't inherit*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split `A` into separate interfaces, which allows sub classes to pick and choose which properties of `A` they wish to inherit.

Take this, for example:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual int getN() = 0;
};

class A1
{
public:
    virtual int getNum() = 0;
};

class B : public A, public A1
{
private:
    int n = 2;
public:
    int getN() override { return n; }
    int getNum() override { return 42;  }
};
class C : public A1
{
public:
    virtual int getNum() override { return 1; }
};
```

Here, `C` no longer needs `getN()` so it inherits only from the interfaces that it needs. This pattern is commonly referred to as the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).