# How Do Member Order Dependencies Influence Initialization Lists In C++?

Tags: c++, coding-style

When I read the post https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#empty-parens-in-object-decl, it has a sample code.

```
class MyString {
public:
  MyString(const MyString& s);              // copy constructor
  // ...
protected:
  unsigned len_;  // ORDER DEPENDENCY
  char*    data_;  // ORDER DEPENDENCY
};
MyString::MyString(const MyString& s)
  : len_ (s.len_)
  , data_(new char[s.len_ + 1u])       
{                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑   // not len_
  memcpy(data_, s.data_, len_ + 1u);
}                        ↑↑↑↑   // no issue using len_ in ctor's {body}
```

at the subsection part `Is it moral for one member object to be initialized using another member object in the initializer expression?`and `What if one member object has to be initialized using another member object?`,it said that:

"In a constructor’s initialization list, it is easiest and safest to avoid using one member object from this object in the initialization expression of a subsequent initializer for this object. Because of this guideline, the constructor that follows uses s.len_ + 1u rather than len_ + 1u, even though they are otherwise equivalent.The s. prefix avoids an unnecessary and avoidable order dependency."

<-- why are `s.len_` and `len_` equivalent? `s.len_` refer to `s`'s `len_`, but `len_` refer to `this`; And in the question I asked days ago [why copy constructor use private property directly in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844477/why-copy-constructor-use-private-property-directly-in-c), LogicStuff said that accessing s.len_ works because it adapts to the `const` instance. It seems the two answers are unrelated.

<-- why does it say that `s.` prefix avoids an unnecessary and avoidable order dependency? Can any one explain order dependency in this situation in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *why are s.len_ and len_ equivalent?*

They're equivalent in *value*. `len_` simply copies the value of `s.len_` in the initialization list, so they'll both store the same size.

> *why does it say that s. prefix avoids an unnecessary and avoidable
>   order dependency? Can any one explain order dependency in this
>   situation in detail?*

This relates to an order dependency between the members of a `class/struct` and its initialization list in the constructor. For example, this is incorrect:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x, y;
    Foo(): y(0), x(0) {} // wrong initialization order
};
```

This is correct:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x, y;
    Foo(): x(0), y(0) {} // right initialization order
};
```

This initialization order can be a source of mistakes. Any kind of changing/reordering of the class's member variables requires updating the initialization lists of the constructor to match the new order. We can't avoid that.

However, in the example listed (version #1):

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString& s)
  : len_ (s.len_)
  , data_(new char[s.len_ + 1u])
```

... if we did this (version #2):

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString& s)
  : len_ (s.len_)
  , data_(new char[len_ + 1u])
```

... we would then have two separate places in the initialization list depending on the order in which `len_` is initialized, not just one. This code immediately above (#2) would be fine, but it's more prone to human mistakes if you ever edit the class data members afterwards.

Because of that, the former version (#1) reduces the number of places that depend on initialization order, and therefore makes it easier to avoid mistakes (present and future).

Comment: why `s` could access `len_` directly? len_ is a private property.

Comment: Oh, that's perfectly fine since it's `MyString` accessing `MyString`. You can think of it crudely like, a "class is always a friend of itself". You can access data members of other instances of the exact same class from within a class method.

Comment: please have a look the comment of the  answer for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844477/why-copy-constructor-use-private-property-directly-in-c/33844497?noredirect=1#comment55599172_33844497. I think you are right, but LogicStuff doesn't think so.

Comment: Oh, LogicStuff is correct there. Here it doesn't have to do with private access (which is legal). It has to do with const-correctness. `getFreq()` can't be called through `const node&` or `const node*` no matter where you're calling from (even within the class itself).

Comment: So that's what he means when he says friendship is irrelevant here. Here it's only about const-correctness. To fix your issue, you have to add "const" to the end of getFreq().

Comment: Put very simple/crudely, whenever you see like `const T&` or `const T*`, where T is any data type, you can only call member functions on it that also have `const` at the end. Also if you're inside a member function which has `const` at the end, you can only call member functions within the same object also marked as `const` (read-only). It's to ensure that when you have something that's supposed to be read-only, you only call functions on it that are likewise marked as read-only.

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one explain order dependency detailedly in this situation?

`len_` is declared before `data_` in your class definition.  Thus `len_` will *always* be initialized first, regardless of the order of the items in the initialization list.

The order that your member variables appear in your class (top-down), is the order that they will be initialized.  The initialization list does not change the ordering.

So what would happen if `len_` appears after `data_` in your class, and what problems can occur?  Let's see:

If your class looked like this:

```
class MyString {
public:
  MyString(const MyString& s);              // copy constructor
  // ...
protected:
  char*    data_;    
  unsigned len_;  
};
```

and then you did this:

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString& s)
  : len_ (s.len_)  
  , data_(new char[len_ + 1u])  // using uninitialized len_ here.     
{ 
   // now len_ is initialized and can be used.                 
   memcpy(data_, s.data_, len_ + 1u);
}
```

A bug is introduced, since `len_` is not yet initialized when used in the call to `new char[]`, even though the initializer list happens to mention `len_` first.  That's why using `s.len_` is guaranteed to work in the initializer list, regardless of the order of declaration of the member variables.

Comment: Does that mean the initialization complete until initialization list go to end?

Comment: All variables that can be default initialized are initialized, top-down in your class definition, before the body of the constructor is entered.  The order of initialization always goes by the order that the variables are declared, that's the bottom line.  The initializer list cannot change this behavior, which is why you must be careful when you use a member within an initializer list.